# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Die erste Meldung'. after adding an item via console

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add an item into db.sqlite3 via command line

```
In [10]: m = Meldung('Die erste Meldung', zeitstempel=datetime.today(), text='Nun kommt das klassische Hallo-Welt-Beispiel.')

In [11]: m.save()
```

but got this error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Die erste Meldung'.
```

Inside migrations\0001_initial.py below the field id of contentobject Meldung  is declared as auto_created=True, but it seems it's not working as expected.

How can I solve it?

- expected result
  Field 'id' is generated automated by db.sqlite3
- environment
  Python 3.8.2
  Django 3.1.3
- models.py

```
from django.db import models




class Meldung(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zeitstempel = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField('Meldungstext')


class Kommentar(models.Model):
    meldung = models.ForeignKey(
        Meldung,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    autor = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    text = models.TextField('Kommentartext')
```

- migrations\0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.3 on 2020-11-04 20:57


from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion




class Migration(migrations.Migration):


    initial = True


    dependencies = [
    ]


    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Meldung',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('titel', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('zeitstempel', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('text', models.TextField(verbose_name='Meldungstext')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Kommentar',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('autor', models.CharField(max_length=70)),
                ('text', models.TextField(verbose_name='Kommentartext')),
                ('meldung', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='news.meldung')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter if you pass the value *positionally* (so without the name of the parameter), is `id`, so you assign `'Die erste Meldung'` not to `title` but to the implicit `id` field.

You can solve this by passing it as a *named* parameter:

```
m = Meldung(
    title='Die erste Meldung',
    zeitstempel=datetime.today(),
    text='Nun kommt das klassische Hallo-Welt-Beispiel.'
)
```

you can also pass `None` to the `id` parameter:

```
m = Meldung(
    None,
    'Die erste Meldung',
    zeitstempel=datetime.today(),
    text='Nun kommt das klassische Hallo-Welt-Beispiel.'
)
```

but it makes it unclear what each value represents in the `Meldung` object, as you found out yourself.

Comment: This is working fine: m = Meldung(
    tittel='Die erste Meldung',
    zeitstempel=datetime.today(),
    text='Nun kommt das klassische Hallo-Welt-Beispiel.'
)